# What steps can I take to resolve the EPERM error in Ubuntu Linux, which is running on VirtualBox within the Windows environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

While working on Windows 11, I'm utilizing Linux's terminal for backend tasks in web development (specifically for Node.js). I've set up Ubuntu through VirtualBox, and unfortunately, I encounter an issue consistently when running commands like 'npm i figlet.' I believe the error is related to permissions (simulinks). I tried to execute the command in an alternative folder and then move it to the shared folder on the linux machine. However, when I move the file it does move part of the file but not the simulinks. If anyone else has faced this problem, could you kindly share how to resolve it or suggest an alternative method to share folders between Windows and Ubuntu Linux?

Here are some screenshots to better understand the problem -

```
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBCgQ.png)
[Virtual Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VfSF.png)
[Shared Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C02PF.png)
[Permission on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNnvA.png)
```

I have looked into the virtual box settings and the shared folder has full access and is auto mounted.

I'm using the shared folder functionality since I use VS Code on my Windows machine for frontend tasks. Any assistance provided would be immensely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I have tried to run the clear cache command, closed VS code while running the command, rebooted both hosts, reinstalled npm multiple times.

I expected to add multiple package in the shared folder on linux so that I can open it on VS code on my Windows machine.

The result is the EPERM error no matter what I tried.